# Save record to production environment

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I need to save records to the production environment instead of the development environment in CloudKit. What I have tried to do in order to manage that is what many have recommended me. Submit a build of the app, and download it using TestFlight. That way, the records will be saved to the production environment, they said.

This is my code for saving records

```
func uploadRecordsToProduction() {
        let cloudContainer = CKContainer(identifier: "MyContainserString")
        let publicDatabase = cloudContainer.publicCloudDatabase

        publicDatabase.saveRecord(record, completionHandler: {_,_ in

        })
    }
```

If I run the app in Xcode simulator the record gets saved in the development environment. If I run the app using Testflight, no record is being saved it seems. What is happening?

Comment: Have you moved your configuration from Development to Production using the CloudKit dashboard?  You can also use an ad-hoc build on your device to test production cloud kit. Checking the error value passed to the completion handler and displaying some sort of alert might also help

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have deployed to production yes. The error says: "Not Authenticated. CloudKit was denied by user settings. Retry after 3.0 seconds"

Comment: I fixed it by upgrading iCloudDrive! Thanks!